# jq json retrieve value from an inner array based on condition and add it outside of array

Tags: arrays, maps, jq, flatten

My Input

```
{
"data": {
    "assets": [{
        "aDASD": "1056bda9-2598-4fdf-bd99-db3924464a75",
        "KEY": "a7e2ef79-41aa-4a36-9ca1-1f388917eb12.ahnl",
        "key2": "store-order-picking-units-api",
        "key3": "1.0.1",
        "tags": [{
                "value": "abcd",
                "key": null,
                "mutable": false
            },
            {
                "value": "rest",
                "key": null,
                "mutable": false
            },
            {
                "value": "123",
                "key": null,
                "mutable": false
            }, {
                "value": "system",
                "key": null,
                "mutable": true
            },
            {
                "value": "market",
                "key": null,
                "mutable": true
            }
        ],
        "type": "mytype"
    }]
}
```

}

I would like to have output as below

```
{
"data": {
    "assets": [{
        "aDASD": "1056bda9-2598-4fdf-bd99-db3924464a75",
        "KEY": "a7e2ef79-41aa-4a36-9ca1-1f388917eb12.ahnl",
        "key2": "store-order-picking-units-api",
        "key3": "1.0.1",
        "tags": [{
                "value": "abcd",
                "key": null,
                "mutable": false
            },
            {
                "value": "rest",
                "key": null,
                "mutable": false
            },
            {
                "value": "123",
                "key": null,
                "mutable": false
            }, {
                "value": "system",
                "key": null,
                "mutable": true
            },
            {
                "value": "market",
                "key": null,
                "mutable": true
            }
        ],
        "type": "mytype",
        "newkey1": "system",
        "newkey2": "market"
    }]
}
```

}

response contains newkey1 and newkey2. Now here comes the tricky part. When populating newkey1, the values can be "system" "process" etc. and for newkey2, the values can be "market", "finance" etc..

In other words, newkey1 should be populated if any of the `.data.assets[].tags[].values` is system or process etc...similarly newkey2 only if market, finance etc.

Is it complex or first of all achievable using jq? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jq is Turing-complete, so you're in luck :-)

Your requirements aren't completely clear, but the following produces the output you expect and should get you on your way:

```
.data.assets |= map(
    .newkey1 = if any(.tags[].value; . == "system") then "system" else null end
  | .newkey2 = if any(.tags[].value; . == "market") then "market" else null end 
)
```

The key points here are:

- `|=` can be used for updates;
- `any(stream; condition)` checks whether the condition is true for any item in the stream

Comment: Genius.! Thanks,